# What other sites are available for debating issues?

Tags: discussion, support, faq, questions

The Philosophy.SE site has fairly strict guidelines regarding the types of questions that should be asked. In particular, open-ended questions that elicit discussion fall outside the scope of this site.

However, I think that many problems/questions in Philosophy *do* require discussion and arguing over different viewpoints, and there are obvious benefits of having access to the diversity of opinions.

What other sites or areas are available where such questions are welcomed?

Comment: Related: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Stack Overflow questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8401)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/philosophy-cafe) to discuss philosophy as much as you'd like. The room has seen a steady growth in usage recently, and you can flag people there (as in, get their attention) by using the @ just like on the site. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'd hate to lead you away from this site (always use chat first, as stoicfury suggested), but if you are bent on using something else, the [Philosophy Forums](http://forums.philosophyforums.com/) are very popular and active - I've been a member for a while, and it's alright. You're sure to find something there.

However, again, Philosophy.SE and the corresponding chat is the best :) things are much more formal and moderated (in a good way) here, you're more likely to get good answers, and there's always a place for argumentation (of course, of the cordial variety).

In summary: Join us, we got cookies. Or at least, [zombies](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/zombies/), which are really cool.

Comment: I checked out that site and a few others. I dislike the forum-style layout because it is not conducive to long discussions. After a few pages they become to hard to read, it's not clear which answers are the best, and there's usually no way to "bump" good posts to the top. Honestly, I prefer the SE format by far; there's nothing one can't ask here when done right. The problem is that people who are philosophy amateurs often do not really know what they are asking so they lack the ability to focus it for the site; they need someone to help clarify their thoughts. That's where chat comes in. :P

Comment: @stoicfury I totally agree with you. I just thought the OP may like it (obviously, some do).

Comment: Yeah, I guess I just wanted to point out that there is very little that cannot be asked here. It's not about asking the right questions, it's about asking questions *right*.

Comment: That last sentence came off really epic, we should turn that into our slogan or something, haha